# Keep rangeSelector visible but disable editing

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to keep the From: ---  To: --- visible with the currently visible date range but disable the click event on the dates which allows editing the date range by writing a new one.

Comment: Are you asking how to 'disable' an element?

Comment: I want to have the 2 input boxes that Highcharts displays in the corner (top-right) which says  From: 2014-05-21  To: 2015-05-30 but don't allow users to click on the dates and write a date manually. I want just those inputs to be visible (but not editable). I used this: $('.highcharts-range-selector-buttons').hide();  which works but now when I click on the dates a little box appears which displays the same date and although that new little box isn't editable I don't want it to even appear.

Comment: Sorry I used this (not the one I said in the above comment): $('.highcharts-range-selector').attr('readonly', true);

Comment: I tried unbinding the click event from the inputs "max" and "min" no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've finally decided to edit Highstock.src.js in order to disable the click event:

These are the lines involved (line 22405 in Highstock JS v2.1.7 (2015-06-26):

```
on('click', function () {
                rangeSelector.showInput(name); // If it is already focused, the onfocus event doesn't fire (#3713)
                rangeSelector[name + 'Input'].focus();
            })
```

Comment: Instead of edit code directly, we advice you to use API for wrapping functions. Ref: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer with a specific piece of code since you haven't provided us with any, but simply using JavaScript to do this is your best bet. Get the element object and just set the `disabled` property:

`document.getElementById("btnGo").disabled = true;`

or jQuery:

```
$('#btnGo').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Just tried it: $('.highcharts-range-selector').attr('disabled', true);  it works partially because when I click on the input box displayed by Highcharts there appears a disabled box which stays there forever... I think this is something specific to highcharts internals. Maybe someone has donde this b efore...